# Trouble calling functions

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I am writing code that deals with calling functions. I am about halfway through, and when I try to compile I get the error "too many arguments to function 'double().' 
Here is my code. Any feedback would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void displayMenu();
double force();

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int menuOption;
    displayMenu();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void displayMenu(void)
{
    int menuOption;
    double weight;
    cout << "           Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 for Force calculation with acceleration = 9.8m/s^2.\n";
    cout << "Enter 2 for Force calculation with user defined acceleration.\n";
    cout << "Enter 3 to quit the program.\n";
    cin >> menuOption;
        if(menuOption==1)
            cout << "Enter a mass.\n";
            cin >> weight;
            cout << force(weight);  
}

double force(double weight)
{
    double force, mass;
    force=(mass*9.8);
    return force;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double force();
```

Up the top you tell the compiler `force()` expects no args

Then you call it passing an arg:

```
cout << force(weight);
```

Compiler says "huh?".

The fix is to let the compiler know that `force` takes an argument. Up the top replace `double force();` with `double force(double);`

Answer (score 1):

Change `double force();` to `double force(double);`